# Terraform error setting S3 bucket tags: InvalidTag: The TagValue you have provided is invalid status code: 400

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I have managed to make my Terraform loop through all of my buckets creating an IAMs user and a bucket

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "aws_s3_buckets" {
  count         = "${length(var.s3_bucket_name)}"
  bucket        = "${var.s3_bucket_name[count.index]}"
  acl           = "private"

  tags = {
    Name        = "${var.s3_bucket_name[count.index]}"
    Environment = "live"
    policy = <<POLICY
{
    "Id": "Policy1574607242703",
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Sid": "Stmt1574607238413",
        "Action": [
          "s3:PutObject"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": {
          "arn:aws:s3:::"."${var.s3_bucket_name[count.index]}"."/*"}
        },
        "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
        "${var.s3_bucket_name[count.index]}"}
        ]}                
      }
    ]
  }
POLICY
}
}
```

I'm getting error setting **S3 bucket tags: InvalidTag: The TagValue you have provided is invalid status code: 400** is there a way to create policies like this?  Or have I done something incorrect in my code?

Comment: The policy section is not part of the tag. If your intention is to create an S3 bucket policy, you need to use the policy argument. If your intention is to create an IAM user, you need to create aws_iam_user and aws_iam_user_policy resources.

Comment: @krishna_mee2004 are you saying I should remove policy and place it outside of the tag?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. policy section is not part of tag.

Comment: Please put it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because `policy` section is not part of `tag` argument. It is a separate section within the aws_s3_bucket resource. You can also use [aws_s3_bucket_policy](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/s3_bucket_policy.html) resource to create bucket policy.

Note: There are quite a few issues with the policy. You would have to fix them for the policy to go through fine. Some of the issues are:

- `"arn:aws:s3:::"."${var.s3_bucket_name[count.index]}"."/*"}` -- this should not be inside a JSON.
- There are some curly braces that are not aligned properly (some extra curly braces).
- The principal should be an IAM resource (IAM User or IAM role or an account or *).

Answer (score 0):

Issue is here in the tags section.

```
tags = {
    Name        = "${var.s3_bucket_name[count.index]}"
    Environment = "live"
    }
```

The Value for Name tag should be `${var.s3_bucket_name.aws_s3_buckets[count.index]}`